# WSO2 IS Passive authentication

Tags: authentication, server, wso2, identity

My client asked for passive authentication capacity in his applications. when I read the documentation, I find information about Passive STS but I'm not sure this is what he's got on mind. The scenario my client is thinking about is the following:

When a user is authenticated in other IdP, the application should be able to obtain transparently user's credentials and attributes.When he's not, the page should be accessed but without the relevant informations of user's identity.

With OpenSAML, it was easy to  add the attribute for passive authentication but WSO2 IS replied he hasn't got the capacity to manage this request. Do you know if WSO2 IS has the capacity to address passive authentication request and how ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't much understand what do you mean by `user is authenticated in other IdP`. regardless that the described scenario would fit for any reasonable authentication (SAML or OAuth) where it is possible to pass additional attributes to the service provider (application). I setup the passive STS a few times already, but usually only the identity (username or email) were needed.

Comment: Hi, this is what I consider to be passive authentication. Tell me, if I'm wrong. At first I thought it would work as follow. The user is authenticated on the same IdP but with a different SP. My SP receives a request from a user not authenticated on my SP, to provide specific contents I ask the IdP if he knows the user. I think he can know him only if the user has already been authenticated. If the IdP knows him, he responds with the user's credentials and attributes. This scenario can extend  to an other IdP if federation is set. When reading the documentation of WSO2, only STS was mentioned.

Comment: So I'd like to know the connection between Passive Authentication and STS. Is it the only to provide it ? And how ?

Comment: you may want to clean the vocabulary - there is `claim based authentication` (OAuth, SAML, STS) and `STS with Passive Requestor Profile` (subset of STS protocol supported by WSO2IS, it looks like SAML just the parameter names and messages are little bit different).  Indeed the IdP serves to achieve SSO - if the user is already authenticated, the user information are passed back to the SP (username and user attributes).

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to send a passive authentication SAML request without the user required to see the roundtrip to IdP ?

Comment: Lets assume we're talking abou the web applications. When you want to achieve SSO (single sign-on), you have to redirect the user as the session is effectively maintained by the web-based cookie. So until you don't want to play some nasty games with iframes, redirecting the user once to authenticate is not so bad..